# Nested JSON and Retrofit flatMap

Tags: android, retrofit

`Trips.json`

```
{
  "trips":[
      {
         "summary": {
            "subTrips":3,
            "changes":1,
            "duration":"1:09",
            "departure":{
               "date":"2017-05-07",
               "time":"11:46",
            },
            "arrival":{
               "date":"2017-05-07",
               "time":"12:55",
            },
         },
         "subTrips":[
            {
               "departure":{
                  "date":"2017-05-07",
                  "time":"11:46",
               },
               "arrival":{
                  "date":"2017-05-07",
                  "time":"12:07",
               },
               "intermediateStopsKey":"c474e7c"
            },
            {
               "departure":{},
               "arrival":{},
               "intermediateStopsKey":"c81e728"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "summary": {},
         "subTrips": [
            { "intermediateStopsKey": "123456" }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

`IntermediateStops.json`

```
{
"status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "stationName": "Husby",
            "arrivalTime": "19:59",
            "departureTime": "19:59",
        },
        {
            "stationName": "Kista",
            "arrivalTime": "20:01",
            "departureTime": "20:01"
        },
        {
            "stationName": "Hallonbergen",
            "arrivalTime": "20:05",
            "departureTime": "20:05"
        }
    ]
}
```

My first API call returns `Trips.json`. `subTrips` contain multiple `intermediateStopsKey` fields. Each `intermediateStopsKey` is a new API call to get the `IntermediateStops.json` which I need to inject into the `Trips.json`.  `flatMap()` seems to be the way to do it, but I need help how to chain up the commands to get the desired result.

```
API().getTrips(params)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnRequest((Long request) -> dummyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> createListView())
                .doOnNext(response -> getTrips(response.body().getData()))
                .flatMap(getTripsModel -> Observable.from(getTripsModel.body().getData().getTrips()))
                .flatMap(tripsModel -> Observable.from(tripsModel.getSubTrips()))
                /********
                ** at some point here I need to insert the 
                ** IntermediateStops into the SubTripsModel
                *********/
                .flatMap(subTripsModel ->
                    API().getIntermediateStops(
                        subTripsModel.getIntermediateStops(), 
                        Token.getInstance().TOKEN))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> dummyView.setVisibility(View.GONE))
                .subscribe(intermediateResponse -> {
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.i("REST ERROR", RestErrorHelper.getErrorMessage(throwable, mContext));
                });
```

The requests are properly being chained, I am unsure on how to insert the results of my getIntermediateStops API calls into their respective SubTripsModels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
API().getTrips(params)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnRequest((Long request) -> dummyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))
                .doOnNext(response -> getTrips(response.body().getData()))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> createListView())
                .flatMap(getTripsModel -> Observable.from(getTripsModel.body().getData().getTrips()))
                .flatMap(tripsModel -> Observable.from(tripsModel.getSubTrips()))
                .map((SubTripsModel subTripsModel) -> API().getIntermediateStops(
                        subTripsModel.getIntermediateStops(), Token.getInstance().TOKEN)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<BaseResponseModel<List<IntermediateStopsModel>>>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Response<BaseResponseModel<List<IntermediateStopsModel>>> baseResponseModelResponse) {
                                subTripsModel.setIntermediateStation(baseResponseModelResponse.body().getData());
                            }
                        }))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> dummyView.setVisibility(View.GONE))
                .subscribe(finalResponse -> {


                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.i("REST ERROR", RestErrorHelper.getErrorMessage(throwable, mContext));
                });
```

This works, for anyone interested, you use `flatMap()` to get yourself deeper into the nested JSON, and when you reach the point where you can iterate over the `subTrips` array of objects you then use the `map()` function and using `subscribe()` you get the option to iterate over each `subTrip` and make your chained calls there.